# Memory Leak in ISampleGrabber

Tags: c#, video, com, directshow, directshow.net

I have implemented this below code. Basically I'm trying to grab a snap from a camera. The code works well for the integrated cam but when an external cam is attached the issue starts. It takes first snap only and the second snap never comes.

Code can be viewed at

```
public class ImageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Image CapturedImage { get; set; }
}

public class Camera
{
    internal DsDevice Device { get; set; }
    internal bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Delay { get; set; }
}

public class DsCameraHelper : ISampleGrabberCB, IDisposable
{

    public void Connect(Camera device)
    {
        if (runningCamera == null)
            runningCamera = device;
        if (runningCamera.Name != device.Name)
        {
            runningCamera.IsRunning = false;
            runningCamera = device;
        }

        if (runningCamera == null) return;
        if (runningCamera.IsRunning)
            capFilter.Run(10);
        else
            PrepareCam();
        captured = false;
        runningCamera.IsRunning = true;

        int hr;
        if (sampGrabber == null)
            return;

        if (savedArray == null)
        {
            int size = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.ImageSize;
            if ((size < 1000) || (size > 16000000))
                return;
            savedArray = new byte[size + 64000];
        }

        hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(this, 1);
    }

    public void Disconnect(Camera device)
    {
        int hr;
        if (sampGrabber == null)
            return;
        hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(null, 0);
    }

    public Bitmap TakeShot()
    {
        return LatestBitmapFrame;
    }

    private object _latestFrameLock = new object();
    private Bitmap _latestFrame = null;
    public Bitmap LatestBitmapFrame
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_latestFrameLock)
            {
                return _latestFrame;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_latestFrameLock)
            {
                _latestFrame = value;
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region private members

    private Panel videoPanel;

    /// <summary> flag to detect first Form appearance </summary>
    private bool firstActive;

    /// <summary> base filter of the actually used video devices. </summary>
    private IBaseFilter capFilter;

    /// <summary> graph builder interface. </summary>
    private IGraphBuilder graphBuilder;

    /// <summary> capture graph builder interface. </summary>
    private ICaptureGraphBuilder2 capGraph;
    private ISampleGrabber sampGrabber;

    /// <summary> control interface. </summary>
    private IMediaControl mediaCtrl;

    /// <summary> event interface. </summary>
    private IMediaEventEx mediaEvt;

    /// <summary> video window interface. </summary>
    private IVideoWindow videoWin;

    /// <summary> grabber filter interface. </summary>
    private IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt;

    /// <summary> structure describing the bitmap to grab. </summary>
    private VideoInfoHeader videoInfoHeader;
    private bool captured = true;
    private int bufferedSize;

    /// <summary> buffer for bitmap data. </summary>
    private byte[] savedArray;

    /// <summary> list of installed video devices. </summary>
    private ArrayList capDevices;

    private const int WM_GRAPHNOTIFY = 0x00008001;  // message from graph

    private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;    
    private const int WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000;
    private const int WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x04000000;


    private delegate void CaptureDone();

    #endregion

    #region SampleGrabber

    int ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB(double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer,
     int BufferLen)
    {
        if (captured || (savedArray == null))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        captured = true;
        bufferedSize = BufferLen;
        if ((pBuffer != IntPtr.Zero) && (BufferLen > 1000) && 
         (BufferLen <= savedArray.Length))
            Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, savedArray, 0, BufferLen);
        OnCaptureDone();
        return 0;
    }

    int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion

    public DsCameraHelper()
    {
        InitDevices();
        Cameras = new List<Camera>();
        videoPanel = new Panel();
        foreach (DsDevice cam in capDevices)
        {

            Cameras.Add(new Camera() { Device = cam, Name = cam.Name });
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<ImageEventArgs> OnSnapShotCompleted;

    public List<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
    Camera runningCamera = null;

    private void PrepareCam()
    {

        if (!StartupVideo(runningCamera.Device.Mon)) return;


    }
    /// <summary> handler for toolbar button clicks. </summary>
    public void ClickImage(Camera device)
    {
        if (runningCamera == null)
            runningCamera = device;
        if(runningCamera.Name != device.Name)
        {
            runningCamera.IsRunning = false;
            runningCamera = device;
        }

        if (runningCamera == null) return;
        if (runningCamera.IsRunning)
            capFilter.Run(10);
        else
            PrepareCam();
        captured = false;
        runningCamera.IsRunning = true;

        int hr;
        if (sampGrabber == null)
            return;

        if (savedArray == null)
        {
            int size = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.ImageSize;
            if ((size < 1000) || (size > 16000000))
                return;
            savedArray = new byte[size + 64000];
        }

        hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(this, 1);

    }

    #region DS Implementation

    private void InitDevices()
    {
        if (!DsUtils.IsCorrectDirectXVersion())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!DsDev.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, 
          out capDevices))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary> capture event, triggered by buffer callback. </summary>
    void OnCaptureDone()
    {
        try
        {
            int hr;
            if (sampGrabber == null)
                return;
            //hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(null, 0);

            int w = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Width;
            int h = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Height;
            if (((w & 0x03) != 0) || (w < 32) || (w > 4096) 
            || (h < 32) || (h > 4096))
                return;
            int stride = w * 3;

            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(savedArray, 
            GCHandleType.Pinned);
            int scan0 = (int)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            scan0 += (h - 1) * stride;
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(w, h, -stride, 
              PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)scan0);
            handle.Free();
            savedArray = null;
            lastFrame = b;

            if (OnSnapShotCompleted != null)
                OnSnapShotCompleted(this, 
             new ImageEventArgs() { CapturedImage = b });
            capFilter.Stop();

            //Dispose();
            //StartupVideo(device.Mon);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
    }
    public Bitmap LastFrame { get { return lastFrame; } }
    private Bitmap lastFrame;
    bool StartupVideo(UCOMIMoniker mon)
    {
        int hr;
        try
        {
            if (!CreateCaptureDevice(mon))
                return false;

            if (!GetInterfaces())
                return false;

            if (!SetupGraph())
                return false;

            if (!SetupVideoWindow())
                return false;


            hr = mediaCtrl.Run();
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            Thread.Sleep(runningCamera.Delay);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    bool GetInterfaces()
    {
        Type comType = null;
        object comObj = null;
        try
        {
            comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Clsid.FilterGraph);
            if (comType == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException(
                @"DirectShow FilterGraph not installed/registered!");
            comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
            graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)comObj; comObj = null;

            Guid clsid = Clsid.CaptureGraphBuilder2;
            Guid riid = typeof(ICaptureGraphBuilder2).GUID;
            comObj = DsBugWO.CreateDsInstance(ref clsid, ref riid);
            capGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)comObj; comObj = null;

            comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Clsid.SampleGrabber);
            if (comType == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException(
              @"DirectShow SampleGrabber not installed/registered!");
            comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
            sampGrabber = (ISampleGrabber)comObj; comObj = null;

            mediaCtrl = (IMediaControl)graphBuilder;
            videoWin = (IVideoWindow)graphBuilder;
            mediaEvt = (IMediaEventEx)graphBuilder;
            baseGrabFlt = (IBaseFilter)sampGrabber;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (comObj != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObj); comObj = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary> create the user selected capture device. </summary>
    bool CreateCaptureDevice(UCOMIMoniker mon)
    {
        object capObj = null;
        try
        {
            Guid gbf = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
            mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref gbf, out capObj);
            capFilter = (IBaseFilter)capObj; capObj = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (capObj != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capObj); capObj = null;
        }

    }

    bool CloseAll()
    {
        videoWin.put_Owner(IntPtr.Zero);
        mediaCtrl.Stop();
        baseGrabFlt = null;
        if (sampGrabber != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sampGrabber); sampGrabber = null;

        if (capGraph != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capGraph); capGraph = null;

        if (graphBuilder != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(graphBuilder); graphBuilder = null;

        if (capFilter != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(capFilter); capFilter = null;
        return true;
    }


    bool SetupVideoWindow()
    {
        int hr;
        try
        {
            // Set the video window to be a child of the main window
            hr = videoWin.put_Owner(videoPanel.Handle);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Set video window style
            hr = videoWin.put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            // Use helper function to position video 
            //window in client rect of owner window
            //ResizeVideoWindow();

            // Make the video window visible, now that 
            //it is properly positioned
            hr = videoWin.put_Visible(DsHlp.OAFALSE);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = mediaEvt.SetNotifyWindow(videoPanel.Handle,
            WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary> build the capture graph for grabber. </summary>
    bool SetupGraph()
    {
        int hr;
        try
        {
            hr = capGraph.SetFiltergraph(graphBuilder);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(capFilter, 
             "Ds.NET Video Capture Device");
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            //DsUtils.ShowCapPinDialog(capGraph, capFilter, this.Handle);

            AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();
            media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
            media.subType = MediaSubType.RGB24;
            media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;        // ???
            hr = sampGrabber.SetMediaType(media);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            Guid cat = PinCategory.Preview;
            Guid med = MediaType.Video;
            hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, 
            capFilter, null, null); // baseGrabFlt 
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            cat = PinCategory.Capture;
            med = MediaType.Video;
            hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, 
            ref med, capFilter, null, baseGrabFlt); // baseGrabFlt 
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            media = new AMMediaType();
            hr = sampGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType(media);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            if ((media.formatType != FormatType.VideoInfo) || 
               (media.formatPtr == IntPtr.Zero))
                throw new NotSupportedException(
              "Unknown Grabber Media Format");

            videoInfoHeader = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
            media.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(media.formatPtr); 
             media.formatPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            hr = sampGrabber.SetBufferSamples(false);
            if (hr == 0)
                hr = sampGrabber.SetOneShot(false);
            if (hr == 0)
                hr = sampGrabber.SetCallback(null, 0);
            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Implementation

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseInterfaces();
    }

    private void CloseInterfaces()
    {
        int hr;
        try
        {
            OnSnapShotCompleted = null;
            lastFrame.Dispose();
            lastFrame = null;
            if (graphBuilder != null)
            {
                hr = graphBuilder.RemoveFilter(capFilter);
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                hr = graphBuilder.RemoveFilter(baseGrabFlt);
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(graphBuilder);
            }

            if (mediaCtrl != null)
            {
                hr = mediaCtrl.Stop();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mediaCtrl);
                mediaCtrl = null;
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            }

            if (mediaEvt != null)
            {
                hr = mediaEvt.SetNotifyWindow(IntPtr.Zero, 
                    WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mediaEvt);
                mediaEvt = null;
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            if (videoWin != null)
            {
                hr = videoWin.put_Visible(DsHlp.OAFALSE);
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
                hr = videoWin.put_Owner(IntPtr.Zero);
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(videoWin);
                videoWin = null;

                videoPanel.Dispose();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(videoPanel);
                videoPanel = null;
            }

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(videoInfoHeader);
            videoInfoHeader = null;

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(baseGrabFlt);
            baseGrabFlt = null;

            if (sampGrabber != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sampGrabber); 
             sampGrabber = null;

            if (capGraph != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(capGraph); capGraph = null;

            if (graphBuilder != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(graphBuilder); 
             graphBuilder = null;

            if (capFilter != null)
            {
                hr = capFilter.Stop();
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(capFilter); capFilter = null;
            }

            if (capDevices != null)
            {
                foreach (DsDevice d in capDevices)
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(d); ;
                }
                capDevices = null;
            }
            foreach (var cam in Cameras)
            {
                cam.Device.Dispose();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cam.Device); 
            }
            Cameras = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    #endregion
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DShowNET.DsCameraHelper c = new DShowNET.DsCameraHelper();
        Console.WriteLine("List of Attached Cams.");
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var cam in c.Cameras)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}. {1}", count++, cam.Name));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}. {1}", count++, "Exit"));

        int choosenCam = 0;
        while (choosenCam != count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a camera to take snapshot");

            var key = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(key, out choosenCam) && choosenCam <= c.Cameras.Count)
            {
                //c.ClickImage(c.Cameras[choosenCam - 1]);
                //var path = string.Format("img_{0}.png", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff"));
                //img.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
                //Console.WriteLine("Image save successfully at " + path);
                var task = GetSnap(c.Cameras[choosenCam - 1]);
                var data = task.Result;
                task.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    private static async Task<Bitmap> GetSnap(Camera cam)
    {
        Bitmap img = null;
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DsCameraHelper helper = new DsCameraHelper();
            AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            EventHandler<ImageEventArgs> eventHandler = delegate(object sender, ImageEventArgs e)
            {
                //img = e.CapturedImage;

                waitHandle.Set();  // signal that the finished event was raised
            };
            helper.OnSnapShotCompleted += eventHandler;
            Camera dev = null;
            foreach (var camera in helper.Cameras)
            {
                Guid cId, coutId;
                if (camera.Name.Equals(cam.Name))
                    dev = camera;
            }

            if (dev != null)
            {
                helper.ClickImage(dev);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Invalid Cam Selected");
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
            helper.OnSnapShotCompleted -= eventHandler;
            helper.Dispose();
            waitHandle.Dispose();
            waitHandle = null;
            helper = null;
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return img;
    }
}
```

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B39C1B1D1F06A02!8546&authkey=!AGuDe-Q_6_sacM0&ithint=folder%2ccs

Thanks.

Comment: Put your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not stop filter graph from frame callack. Do your thing in the callback and return immediately (without `OnCaptureDone` and friends), stop capture from top level code where you built and started filter graph in first place.

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked. There was a mistake in closeInterface method which was causing the problem.